# C++17, making a variadic template that uses an std::variant that is dependant on template params?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, variant

Is there a way, in C++17, to specify a variant where each entry in the variant has been modified from a variadic template in some repeated way?

In particular, I want to declare a template that may look something like this, declaring an `std::variant` member, something like:

```
template<typename... Args> class Contains {
      ...
    std::variant<...> choices;
      ...
}
```

Such that, for example, `Contains<Type1, Type2, Type3,....>` would have its `choices` member be `std::variant<const Type1 *, const Type2 *, const Type3 *, ....>`. where the supplied types may not necessarily share a common base class.  That is, each supplied type to the template becomes a const pointer in the std::variant.

I know that I could potentially manually specify each entry passed to the template as the necessary pointer type directly, I am wondering if there is some way to use variadic templates to make the declaration easier to enter using only the names of base types for the `Contains` template?

Comment: `std::variant<const Args*...>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
template <typename... Args>
class Contains
{
    std::variant<const Args*...> choices;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just supply the same type with the `const` modifier to your `choices` declaration in the `Contains` class.

```
template <typename... Args>
class Contains
  {
    std::variant<const Args*...> choices;
  };
}
```